# How to suppress the product analytics notification bar within Brave Browser initiated through Selenium and ChromeDriver using Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, brave-browser

I'm able to lauch the Brave Browser using Selenium, ChromeDriver and Python

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

But I'm unable to get rid of the product analytics notification bar almost similar to the *Google Chrome* notification bar.

[image: barve_product_analytics_notification_bar]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is it a notification bar? --disable-notifications or useAutomationExtension try one of those maybe?

Answer (score 5):

I have never used the Brave Browser, so thanks for opening this question.

@flydev had pointing out the Brave switches.

**Switches in pref_names.cc in Brave's code base**

```
#include "brave/components/p3a/pref_names.h"

namespace brave {

const char kP3AEnabled[] = "brave.p3a.enabled";
const char kP3ANoticeAcknowledged[] = "brave.p3a.notice_acknowledged";

}
```

**Again from the Brave code base:**

```
// New users are shown the P3A notice via the welcome page.
registry->RegisterBooleanPref(kP3ANoticeAcknowledged, first_run);
```

```
void BraveConfirmP3AInfoBarDelegate::Create(
    infobars::ContentInfoBarManager* infobar_manager,
    PrefService* local_state) {
  
   // Don't show infobar if:
   // - P3A is disabled
   // - notice has already been acknowledged
   if (local_state) {
    if (!local_state->GetBoolean(brave::kP3AEnabled) ||
        local_state->GetBoolean(brave::kP3ANoticeAcknowledged)) {
      local_state->SetBoolean(brave::kP3ANoticeAcknowledged, true);
      return;
    }
  }

  infobar_manager->AddInfoBar(
      CreateConfirmInfoBar(std::unique_ptr<ConfirmInfoBarDelegate>(
          new BraveConfirmP3AInfoBarDelegate(local_state))));
}


void BraveConfirmP3AInfoBarDelegate::InfoBarDismissed() {
  // Mark notice as acknowledged when infobar is dismissed
  if (local_state_) {
    local_state_->SetBoolean(brave::kP3ANoticeAcknowledged, true);
  }
}


bool BraveConfirmP3AInfoBarDelegate::Cancel() {
  // OK button is "Disable"
  // Clicking should disable P3A
  if (local_state_) {
    local_state_->SetBoolean(brave::kP3AEnabled, false);
  }
  return true;
}
```

I tried to use these switches with
`selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities`.

**Code snippet**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = Options()
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME

prefs = {
    'brave.p3a.enabled': True,
    'brave.p3a.notice_acknowledged': False
}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

Unfortunately this did not work. When I checked Brave Browser's github account I found this item:

- [P3A: command line option to dismiss/hide prompt #17143](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/17143)

As you can see this is a known issue.  I will keep looking for a method that uses `DesiredCapabilities`.

In the meantime, you can pass a Brave profile to the driver, which suppresses the acknowledgement notification.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default")

chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

sleep(60)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

You have to disable these items in the Brave Browser before using the profile.

[image]

Here is the browser with Profile 1 and no acknowledgement notification box.

[image]

Comment: I was going to link this unanswered github issue explaining why I written the answer here, I added a sentence about the `capabilities` 

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it's not possible anymore and I don't really know the real reason behind this, but there is at least two reasons.

The first is that the command-line switch `--p3a-upload-enabled` was optional and only available before Brave `beta-test`.
And the second, it's certainly related to **privacy**, **GDPR** and **internal policies** as the P3A Brave feature doesn't collect personal information but still collect telemetry data with software quality in mind.

You will get more information about this part on their blog: https://brave.com/privacy-preserving-product-analytics-p3a/

---

As argument, you can take a look at this [commit](https://github.com/brave/brave-core/commit/c183adb3bda44e409a4a33ce80cdeeb20ac0e234), more precisely on lines [L13](https://github.com/brave/brave-core/commit/c183adb3bda44e409a4a33ce80cdeeb20ac0e234#diff-1dd9ac767b75d184cd23718420a4076ad9f3ab601aad35e24dca90ee3e8e330aL13), [L79-L80](https://github.com/brave/brave-core/commit/c183adb3bda44e409a4a33ce80cdeeb20ac0e234#diff-a33b19e9ca63f9e20878ea0bd260edc3011805beb41f741d16fb04173bb742e2L79-L80) and [L212-L221](https://github.com/brave/brave-core/commit/c183adb3bda44e409a4a33ce80cdeeb20ac0e234#diff-81bc6015f9d9f6114e126414165fbdd10374ab0fc0059e6aaaba3135be51142cL212-L221) where they removed the switch `--p3a-upload-enabled`.

---

To get back to your issue, if you are not requried to run `chromedriver` profileless, then just **set a profile**, once the browser is running, you can close the notification bar, **the closed state will be saved** in the profile and on the next run, the bar will be hidden.

The following code will create a profile when the WebDriver is instanciated:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()

# set profile path
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\BrowserDrivers\\Test_Profile\\")
# optional, will be relative to `user-data-dir` switch value
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=test_data")

options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

And,

Once the WebDriver run, you will find the following config part in the **Preferences** file which can be found inside the **Profile folder**.

```
{
  "brave": {
    "p3a": {
      "enabled": "false",
      "notice_acknowledged": "true"
    }
  },
  "p3a": {
    "last_rotation_timestamp": "13285608876785125"
  }
}
```

The solution could be to set theses preferences on WebDriver instanciation:

```py
# try to disable P3A via prefs
# ref: https://github.com/brave/brave-core/blob/master/components/p3a/pref_names.cc
chrome_prefs = {"brave":{"p3a":{"enabled":"false","notice_acknowledged":"true"},"widevine_opted_in":"false"},"p3a":{"last_rotation_timestamp":"13285608876785125"}}
options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
```

Unfornutely, I couldn't managed to get it working, despite no error - if you do it, please ping me :)

And if you ask me if we can set the capabilities after the instanciation of the WebDriver, then again I would say nop, as of the current implementation of Selenium, once the WebDriver instance is configured with our intended configuration through DesiredCapabilities class and initialize the WebDriver session to open a Browser, **we cannot change the capabilities runtime**.

Answer (score 0):

When I search Google for: [C# Selenium "Brave uses completely private product analytics to estimate the overall usage of certain features"](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23%20Selenium%20%22Brave%20uses%20completely%20private%20product%20analytics%20to%20estimate%20the%20overall%20usage%20of%20certain%20features)

This page came up first in the results the rest of the results appearing unrelated.

So, I will post my answer for C# here even though this was a Python question originally. It may help Python coders as well. I upvoted @Life is complex for leading me down the magic path. Thanks

***Note: Because this software updates so often I am also adding the exact versions and download locations that it is working with.

*Brave Browser Version:* 1.57.47
*Chromium:* 116.0.5845.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)

*Official Chrome Driver Downloads:* https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

// ...

// Removes: "Brave is being controlled by automated test software."
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");

// Removes: "Brave uses completely private product analytics to estimate the overall usage of certain features."
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("brave.p3a.notice_acknowledged", true);

return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Hope that helps.

Happy coding!!!